# how to Dynamically create a python nested dictionary from sqlalchemy data

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a situation where I'm using sqlalchemy reflection to get the table and column names from a database. From there, I need to put that info into a nested json that looks something like this:

```
{ "root" : "database_name", "children": [
    {"table": "table_name1", "children": [
          {"column": "column_name1"}, {"column": "column_name2"}, {etc} ]
    },
 {"table": "table_name2", "children": [
          {"column": "column_name1"}, {"column": "column_name2"}, {etc} ]
    },
 ]
}
```

I have no problem getting the data I need from the database, but I can't seem to find a decent way to get it from there into a dictionary so I can convert it to a json. I've seen people using various methods, but because I have the same key values in the nests, all I end up doing is overwriting the values rather than adding to the dictionary. Is there some way to do this?